# Unrecognized Expression in Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation within an ember-cli based application and whilst the application runs fine on my laptop (OS X running Google Chrome) it always throws up an error whilst running tests; `unrecognized expression: [data-'Times New Roman'-offcanvas]`.

I also see the same error when running the application normally in IE9 and below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent this error being thrown during Zurb Foundation init set this before explicitly initialising Foundation:

```
Foundation.global.namespace = '';
```

Then proceed as normal:

```
$(document).foundation({
  offcanvas: { ... },
  ...
});
```